# Changing the angle / curvature of a mesh created using python and parametric equations

Tags: parametric, parametrization, python

Changing the angle / curvature of a mesh created using python and parametric equations.

**I can create a Hyperboloid using Python and parametric equations**

[image: img1]

**Python script formula snippet:**

```
for i in range (0, num_x):
        for j in range(0,num_y):
            # nomalize range
                    
            u = 8*(i/num_x-1/2)
            v = 2*math.pi*(j/(num_y-1)-1/2)
            
            x = math.sqrt(1+u**2)*math.cos(v)*uval_a/2
            y = math.sqrt(1+u**2)*math.sin(v)*uval_a/2
            z = uval_b*(u)/(2*math.pi/1)
            # uval_a changes the diameter of center hole
            # uval_b changes the height
            
  
            vert = (x,y,z)
            verts.append(vert)
```

My goal is to create a **mesh** which **curves left** and **curves right** **using Python and Parametric Equations**, similar to the image below.

[image: img2]

I want to say that the issue is with the **U** and **V** variables but I'm not exactly sure how to change these to cause those types of curvatures in the mesh.

Comment: There are many possibilities. To be clear you may need to define the central lines (meridians)  which in the first case is a hyperboloid. Secondly  are mesh helical angles constant for the second case?

Comment: @Narasimham Yes, I do think the helical angles are constant but they don't have to be.  The goal is to animate different variables and see how it affects / changes the mesh.

Answer (score 0):

This is not `Python`, but `Mathematica`... Not what you wanted but it is another example exercise to see how  the parameters are written differently or how their domain limits are set.

```
ParametricPlot3D[{(4 - Sqrt[2 + u^2]) Cos[
    u - v], (4 - Sqrt[2 + u^2]) Sin[u - v], (u + v)^2}, {u, -1, 
  1}, {v, -2, 2}, Boxed -> False, Axes -> None]
ParametricPlot3D[{Sqrt[1 + u^2] Cos[v], Sqrt[1 + u^2] Sin[v], 
  u}, {u, -4, 4}, {v, -Pi, Pi}, Boxed -> False, Axes -> None]
```

[image]